# R: Error Using pool() on lm Model Summary

Tags: r

Need some assistance in R. I ran the `lm()` function and assigned it to variable. Then I used that variable to retrieve summary using `pool()` function.

Here's the code but getting argument data is missing. I saw same example but didn't get that error.

```r
modelFit1 <- with(imputed,lm(MPG ~ CYLINDERS+SIZE+HP+WEIGHT+ACCEL+ENG_TYPE))
summary(pool(modelFit1))
```

> Error in pool(modelFit1) : argument "data" is missing, with no default

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing anything on the issue to get some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error.  In my case it was due to conflicting packages.  I had loaded packages: "mice" and "mi", and "mitools", among others. There is no 'data' argument necessary for 'pool' in the "mice" package, but `mi::pool` does require a data argument.  If you are using mice and following examples in mice's documentation, Try

```
pooled <- mice::pool(modelFit1))

summary(pooled)
```